# Azure Storage Explorer - Save results of query into a variable to be used in another query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-storage-explorer

Is it possible to save the query results into a variable, then use that variable to make a separate query in Azure Storage Explorer?

I.E.

First Query
Select C.ID from C where C.Temp <> '' - This will return results of ID. Need to save this into variable.

Second Query
Select * From C Where C.Temp2 IN (@Variable)

Edited to include sample data:

First set up data

```
{
  "id": <string>,
  "Temp": <string>, 
  "name": <string>,
  "Address": <string>,
  "City": <string>
}
```

Second set of data

```
{
  "id": <string>,
  "Temp2": <string>, 
  "name2": <string>,
  "Address2": <string>,
  "City2": <string>
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is related to something in the portal? FYI you might want to check out subqueries, which might help with what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've looked into subqueries but am unable to due to it being a non-correlated query

Comment: @genius26 It will be helpful if you can share sample data stored in database.

Comment: @RitikaNalwaya, updated to include sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage Explorer support storing structured, non-relational data.

As per my understanding Azure Storage Explorer doesn't support sub-queries or parameterized queries. It support basic filter and sorting operations.
To perform complex operations/queries you may need to use Azure explorer SDK.

**References :-**

- [Table-storage-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-overview)
- [Storage-explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/azure/storage-explorer-table-query)
- [Supported query operators-LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service?source=recommendations)